# How do I find the number of sides of a regular polygon given only its side length and area?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

How do I find the number of sides of a regular polygon given only  its side length and area?

Absolutely no IDEA where to start. Anyone?

Comment: Do you have any further information, e.g. is it a _regular_ polygon or a _cyclic_ polygon, or anything like that?

Comment: regular polygon. Making edits now.

Comment: Divide the $ \ n-$ gon into $ \ n \ $ isoceles triangles.  The apex angle of each is $ \ \frac{360º}{n} \ $ .  The Law of Cosines will give you the lengths of the sides of these triangles in terms of the base lengths, which are the lengths of the sides of the polygon.  You can now find a relation for the area of each triangle in terms of $ \ n \ $ and the length of a side of the polygon, and thus the total area of the polygon in those terms.

Comment: Post this as an answer, please, so I can grant you your well deserved reputation! :)

If you could elaborate a bit more, that would be great, but either way, awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I was describing in my comment (which was all I had time to write then) is similar to the one given by **Michael Hardy**, but does not require finding the altitude of a triangle.  The regular polygon with $ \ n \ $ sides ("regular $ \ n-$ gon") is divided up into $ \ n \ $ isosceles triangles arranged around the centroid of the figure, giving them an "apex angle" of $ \ \frac{2 \pi}{n} \ . $ The base of each triangle is a side $ \ s \ $ of the polygon, and the other (congruent) legs of the triangle will be said to have length $ \ L \ . $

[image]

The Law of Cosines gives us

$$  s^2 \ = L^2 \ + \ L^2 \ - \ 2 \cdot L \cdot L \cdot \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} \  = \ 2  L^2 \ (1 \ - \ \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} ) $$

and the "included angle" formula for the area of a triangle yields

$$ A_{tri} \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot L \cdot L \cdot \sin \frac{2 \pi}{n} \ . $$

From these results, we can write the area of the triangle in terms of $ \ n \ $ and $ \ s \ $ as

$$ A_{tri} \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \  \left[ \frac{s^2}{2  \ (1 \ - \ \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} )}  \right] \cdot \sin \frac{2 \pi}{n} \ =  \   \left[ \frac{\sin \frac{2 \pi}{n}}{4  \ (1 \ - \ \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} )}  \right] \cdot s^2 \ . $$

The polygon comprises $ \ n \ $ of these triangles, so its area is

$$ A(n) \ = \ \left[  \frac{n \ \sin \frac{2 \pi}{n}}{4  \ (1 \ - \ \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} )}  \right] \cdot s^2 \ .  \ \  \ \mathbf{ [1] }$$

Using the "small-angle approximations" for the trigonometric functions of the apex angle as $ \ n \ \rightarrow \ \infty \ , $ we find that

$$ A(n) \ \rightarrow \ \left[  \frac{n \ \cdot  \frac{2 \pi}{n}}{4  \ (1 \ - \ [ \ 1 \ - \ \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{2 \pi}{n} \right)^2 \ ] \ )}   \right] \cdot s^2 \ = \ \frac{n^2 \cdot s^2}{4 \pi} \ , $$

producing the relation described by **Henry** (with the appropriate dimension -- I believe he is using unit side lengths).

Equation **1** above will give us the usual area formulas for equilateral triangles, squares, etc., but the enclosed area also tends to infinity as $ \ n \ $ does, since we are using a *fixed* side length.  If we instead consider the perimeter $ \ p \ $ for the polygon, and write the share of that perimeter represented by each side as $ \ s = \frac{p}{n} \ , $ then we may also express our result as

$$ A(n) \ = \ \left[  \frac{n \ \sin \frac{2 \pi}{n}}{4  \ (1 \ - \ \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} )}  \right] \cdot \left( \frac{p}{n} \right)^2 \ = \ \left[  \frac{ \sin \frac{2 \pi}{n}}{4n  \ (1 \ - \ \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} )}  \right] \cdot p^2 \ \rightarrow \ \frac{p^2}{4 \pi} \ . $$

The limit does indeed give the relation between the area and circumference of a circle.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the number of sides; let $A$, $B$ be the two endpoints of one side of length $s$; let $O$ be the center.  Then $\angle AOB = \dfrac{360^\circ}{n}$.  Take $AB$ to be the base of the triangle $AOB$.  Then the height $h$ satisfies
$$
\frac{s/2}{h} = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \tan \left(\frac 1 2 \cdot \frac{360^\circ}{n}\right).
$$

Given that you can find $h$.  Then
$$
\text{polygon area} = n\cdot(\text{area of triangle $AOB$}).
$$
And so on . . .

I think the bottom line can be expressed without transcendental functions like the tangent.  I'll think about how to do that later.

Answer (score 1):

If the area is $A$ and there are $n$ sides then $A=\dfrac{n}{4\tan\frac{\pi}{n}} \approx \dfrac{n^2}{4\pi}$ for large $n$ so $n \approx \sqrt{4 \pi A}$.  Note that for a circle, the circumference is the square root of the product of $4\pi$ and the area, so this makes sense.

In fact, looking at small values, we need to take the ceiling so  $n=\bigg\lceil \sqrt{4 \pi A} \bigg\rceil$.

Comment: As RecklessReckoner has said, I assumed the side length was $s=1$.  So more generally $A=s^2\dfrac{n}{4\tan\frac{\pi}{n}} \approx s^2\dfrac{ n^2}{4\pi}$ for large $n$ so $n \approx \dfrac{\sqrt{4 \pi A}}{s}$, and more precisely $n=\bigg\lceil \dfrac{\sqrt{4 \pi A}}{s} \bigg\rceil$